# Swashbuckle not generating example xml correctly for array\list properties

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

It seems swashbuckle\swagger-ui (5.6 - using swagger-ui) does not generate example XML correctly when the model has a property that is a list.

To see this issue:

1 - Create an empty webapi project (I'm using asp.net)

2 - Add a couple of example models (I went with Customer + Order for testing)

```
public class Customer
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("Orders"),XmlArrayItem("Order")]
    public List<Order> Orders { get;set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber { get;set; }
}
```

3 - Create a controller using FromBody to bind to model

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    public void Post([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        customer.ToString();
    }
}
```

4 - Change web api config to allow simple XML

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;  //ADD THIS
    }
}
```

5 - Run site and using /swagger ui change parameter content type to xml and select example model.  You will find the example is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customer>
  <AccountNumber>string</AccountNumber>
  <Orders>
    <OrderNumber>string</OrderNumber>
  </Orders>
</Customer>
```

6 - Submit this with a breakpoint on the customer.ToString() line in the controller and you will find the Orders collection is empty

7 - Modify the XML in swagger-ui to the following and submit:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customer>
  <AccountNumber>string</AccountNumber>
  <Orders>
    <Order><OrderNumber>string</OrderNumber></Order>
  </Orders>
</Customer>
```

8 - The `Customer.Orders` collection is now correctly populated.

What is the best way to fix or workaround this in Swashbuckle?

(There are a few discussions around this and whether it's a bug in swagger-ui or Swashbuckle, but I'm specifically interested in working around it using Swashbuckle)

Comment: I think this is https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4274, though your write up matches the problem I'm having a lot more clearly than the github issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @mutex, but I found that I needed to make another adjustment to it:

```
internal class SwaggerFixArraysInXmlFilter : Swashbuckle.Swagger.ISchemaFilter
{
    // this fixes a Swagger bug that wasn't generating correct XML elements around List<> or array[] types
    public void Apply(Swashbuckle.Swagger.Schema schema, Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, System.Type type)
    {
        // Fix issues with xml array examples not generating correctly
        if (!type.IsValueType)
        {
            schema.xml = new Swashbuckle.Swagger.Xml { name = type.Name };
            if (schema.properties != null)
            {
                foreach (var property in schema.properties)
                {
                    //Array property, which wraps its elements
                    if (property.Value.type == "array")
                    {
                        property.Value.xml = new Swashbuckle.Swagger.Xml
                        {
                            name = $"{property.Key}",
                            wrapped = true
                        };
                        property.Value.items.xml = new Swashbuckle.Swagger.Xml
                        {
                            name = $"{property.Value.items.type}",
                            wrapped = true
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this as answer for now as I never did get around to figuring out why my repro was behaving differently to full implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Abacus, but I found that I needed to make another adjustment to it. (String is not a ValueType, so it was renaming any string value to <String>string</String>... May have something to do with .NET Core 3.1)

```
internal class SwaggerFixArraysInXmlFilter : Swashbuckle.Swagger.ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        Type type = context.Type;

        // Fix issues with xml array examples not generating correctly
        if (!type.IsValueType && type.Name != "String")
        {
            schema.Xml = new OpenApiXml { Name = type.Name };
            if (schema.Properties != null)
            {
                foreach (var property in schema.Properties)
                {
                    //Array property, which wraps its elements
                    if (property.Value.Type == "array")
                    {
                        property.Value.Xml = new OpenApiXml
                        {
                            Name = $"{property.Key}",
                            Wrapped = true
                        };
                        property.Value.Items.Xml = new OpenApiXml
                        {
                            Name = $"{property.Value.Items.Type}",
                            Wrapped = true
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following works:

1 - Add an implementation of ISchemaFilter

```
internal class ApplySchemaVendorExtensions : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {
        // Fix issues with xml array examples not generating correctly
        if (!type.IsValueType)
        {
            schema.xml = new Xml { name = type.Name };
            if(schema.properties != null)
            {
                foreach (var property in schema.properties)
                {
                    //Array property, which wraps its elements
                    if (property.Value.type == "array")
                    {
                        property.Value.xml = new Xml
                        {
                            name = $"{property.Key}",
                            wrapped = true
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2 - Comment this line into SwaggerConfig.cs

```
c.SchemaFilter<ApplySchemaVendorExtensions>();
```

Repeat the test in the Question and the example XML now works directly. As always I'm curious if there's a better solution...

EDIT: Actually this oddly works in the original project I have this issue, but in the small reproduction project for this Quesion it behaves slightly differently! I will edit this answer when I find why...

Comment: To complete the solution above add the following usings

using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net Core 2.2 with Swagger v5, you will need the below code set

```
internal class SwaggerFixArraysInXmlFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            Type type = context.Type;

            // Fix issues with xml array examples not generating correctly
            if (!type.IsValueType)
            {
                schema.Xml = new OpenApiXml { Name = type.Name };
                if (schema.Properties != null)
                {
                    foreach (var property in schema.Properties)
                    {
                        //Array property, which wraps its elements
                        if (property.Value.Type == "array")
                        {
                            property.Value.Xml = new OpenApiXml
                            {
                                Name = $"{property.Key}",
                                Wrapped = true
                            };
                            property.Value.Items.Xml = new OpenApiXml
                            {
                                Name = $"{property.Value.Items.Type}",
                                Wrapped = true
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following `ISchemaFilter` (.NET 6.0, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.5.0):

```cs
public class XmlSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    private static string TakeChars(string src, int charCount)
    {
        if (charCount <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(charCount), $@"{nameof(charCount)} must be greater than 0");
        }

        return src.Length <= charCount
            ? src
            : src[..charCount];
    }

    private static string SafeSubstring(string src, int startIndex)
    {
        if (startIndex < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex), $@"{nameof(startIndex)} must be greater than or equal to 0");
        }

        return src.Length - 1 < startIndex
            ? string.Empty
            : src[startIndex..];
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema.Properties == null)
            return;

        var type = context.Type;

        if (type.GetCustomAttribute<ApplyXmlSchemaFilterAttribute>() == null)
            return;

        var typeXmlRootAttribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<XmlRootAttribute>();
        if (typeXmlRootAttribute != null)
        {
            schema.Xml ??= new OpenApiXml();
            schema.Xml.Name = typeXmlRootAttribute.ElementName;
        }

        var typeProperties = type.GetProperties();

        var excludedProperties = typeProperties
            .Where(t =>
                t.GetCustomAttribute<XmlIgnoreAttribute>()
                != null)
            .ToList();

        // remove excluded properties ([XmlIgnore])
        foreach (var schemaProperty in schema.Properties.ToArray())
        {
            if (excludedProperties.Any(ep =>
                    string.Equals(ep.Name, schemaProperty.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                schema.Properties.Remove(schemaProperty.Key);
            }
        }

        var restTypeProperties = typeProperties.Except(excludedProperties).ToList();

        // rename properties according to [XmlAttribute], [XmlElement], [XmlRoot], etc.
        foreach (var typeProperty in restTypeProperties)
        {
            var camelCaseKey = TakeChars(typeProperty.Name, 1).ToLowerInvariant() + SafeSubstring(typeProperty.Name, 1);
            var normalKey = typeProperty.Name;

            var (propSchemaKey, propSchema) = typeProperty.Name switch
            {
                not null when schema.Properties.TryGetValue(camelCaseKey, out var openApiSchema) => (camelCaseKey, openApiSchema),
                not null when schema.Properties.TryGetValue(normalKey, out var openApiSchema) => (normalKey, openApiSchema),
                _ => (null, null),
            };

            if (propSchemaKey == null || propSchema == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            propSchema.Xml ??= new OpenApiXml();

            if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlTextAttribute>() is not null)
            {
                schema.Properties.Remove(propSchemaKey);
                schema.Type = "string";
                schema.Format = null;
            }
            else if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlElementAttribute>() is { } xmlElementAttribute)
            {
                propSchema.Xml.Name = xmlElementAttribute.ElementName;
            }
            else if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlAttributeAttribute>() is { } xmlAttributeAttribute)
            {
                propSchema.Xml.Name = xmlAttributeAttribute.AttributeName;
                propSchema.Xml.Attribute = true;
            }
            else if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlArrayAttribute>() is { } xmlArrayAttribute)
            {
                propSchema.Xml.Name = xmlArrayAttribute.ElementName;
            }
            else
            {
                propSchema.Xml.Name = typeProperty.Name;
            }

            if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlArrayItemAttribute>() is { } xmlArrayItemAttribute
                && type.Name != "String"
                && propSchema.Type == "array")
            {
                // array property, which wraps its elements
                propSchema.Xml.Wrapped = true;

                if (typeProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    propSchema.Items = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(
                        typeProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0],
                        context.SchemaRepository,
                        typeProperty);
                }

                propSchema.Items.Xml ??= new OpenApiXml();
                propSchema.Items.Xml.Name = xmlArrayItemAttribute.ElementName;
                propSchema.Items.Xml.Wrapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The model should have `ApplyXmlSchemaFilterAttribute`:

```cs
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ApplyXmlSchemaFilterAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iv Altered the answer of @npravdin slightly based on some of the info from this issue https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/225
as the schema was not populating correctly for the items within the array for me.

```
public class XmlSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    private static string TakeChars(string src, int charCount)
    {
        if (charCount <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(charCount), $@"{nameof(charCount)} must be greater than 0");
        }

        return src.Length <= charCount
            ? src
            : src[..charCount];
    }

    private static string SafeSubstring(string src, int startIndex)
    {
        if (startIndex < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex), $@"{nameof(startIndex)} must be greater than or equal to 0");
        }

        return src.Length - 1 < startIndex
            ? string.Empty
            : src[startIndex..];
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema.Properties == null)
            return;

        var type = context.Type;

        if (type.GetCustomAttribute<ApplyXmlSchemaFilterAttribute>() == null)
            return;

        var typeXmlRootAttribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<XmlRootAttribute>();
        if (typeXmlRootAttribute != null)
        {
            schema.Xml ??= new OpenApiXml();
            schema.Xml.Name = typeXmlRootAttribute.ElementName;
        }

        var typeProperties = type.GetProperties();

        var excludedProperties = typeProperties
            .Where(t =>
                t.GetCustomAttribute<XmlIgnoreAttribute>()
                != null)
            .ToList();

        // remove excluded properties ([XmlIgnore])
        foreach (var schemaProperty in schema.Properties.ToArray())
        {
            if (excludedProperties.Any(ep =>
                    string.Equals(ep.Name, schemaProperty.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                schema.Properties.Remove(schemaProperty.Key);
            }
        }

        var restTypeProperties = typeProperties.Except(excludedProperties).ToList();

        // rename properties according to [XmlAttribute], [XmlElement], [XmlRoot], etc.
        foreach (var typeProperty in restTypeProperties)
        {
            var camelCaseKey = TakeChars(typeProperty.Name, 1).ToLowerInvariant() + SafeSubstring(typeProperty.Name, 1);
            var normalKey = typeProperty.Name;

            var (propSchemaKey, propSchema) = typeProperty.Name switch
            {
                not null when schema.Properties.TryGetValue(camelCaseKey, out var openApiSchema) => (camelCaseKey, openApiSchema),
                not null when schema.Properties.TryGetValue(normalKey, out var openApiSchema) => (normalKey, openApiSchema),
                _ => (null, null),
            };

            if (propSchemaKey == null || propSchema == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            propSchema.Xml ??= new OpenApiXml();

            if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlTextAttribute>() is not null)
            {
                schema.Properties.Remove(propSchemaKey);
                schema.Type = "string";
                schema.Format = null;
            }
            else if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlElementAttribute>() is { } xmlElementAttribute)
            {
                propSchema.Xml.Name = xmlElementAttribute.ElementName;
            }
            else if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlAttributeAttribute>() is { } xmlAttributeAttribute)
            {
                propSchema.Xml.Name = xmlAttributeAttribute.AttributeName;
                propSchema.Xml.Attribute = true;
            }
            else if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlArrayAttribute>() is { } xmlArrayAttribute)
            {
                propSchema.Xml.Name = xmlArrayAttribute.ElementName;
            }
            else
            {
                propSchema.Xml.Name = typeProperty.Name;
            }

            if (typeProperty.GetCustomAttribute<XmlArrayItemAttribute>() is { } xmlArrayItemAttribute
                && type.Name != "String"
                && propSchema.Type == "array")
            {
                // array property, which wraps its elements
                propSchema.Xml.Wrapped = true;

                if (typeProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    propSchema.Items = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(
                        typeProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0],
                        context.SchemaRepository,
                        typeProperty);
                }

                //Schema for array elements.
                propSchema.Items = new OpenApiSchema()
                {
                    AllOf = new List<OpenApiSchema>() { new OpenApiSchema() { Reference = propSchema.Items.Reference } },
                    //For complex type, Type is null, for simple type i.e string, type is string.
                    Type = propSchema.Items?.Type ?? "object",

                    Xml = new OpenApiXml()
                    {
                        Name = xmlArrayItemAttribute.ElementName,
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```